# Converting date into mysql format not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert ClassID, TestID and Deadline into a database table, and it seems that the format of my date is not allowing the INSERT query to work. I've tried converting it with this method but it isn't working. When I run my function, it returns "Data cannot be inserted". When I echo $date in the function it gives: 2016-12-01

My function:

```
public function createAssignment($theClassID,$dueDate)
{
    $testID = $_SESSION['currentTestID'];

    $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dueDate']);
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

    echo $date;

    $sql="INSERT INTO settest (ClassID, TestID, Deadline) VALUES ('$theClassID', '$testID', $date)";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Data cannot be inserted");
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype for deadline field

Comment: Are you sure that all parameters has right type (as in MySQL)?
Also you miss to add `' '` for `$date`

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string with mysqli_query not sure if that would work

Comment: @HappyCoding stored as 'date' and the name is 'dueDate'

Comment: @KurtGörg: echo $sql and run that SQL query in MySQL console and see what the error it is giving.

Comment: @RaunakGupta Thanks I found the problem. I was trying to enter the same composite key again, so it didn't work.

Comment: Just a small tip: use prepared statements. It's much better than `mysql_real_escape_string` which is deprecated and removed in later PHP versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I was entering the same data multiple times, and therefore the composite key was being repeated. Works now

Answer (score 0):

You should add single quotes to `$date` variable in the sql query.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO settest (ClassID, TestID, Deadline) VALUES ('$theClassID', '$testID', '$date')";
```

Comment: Just noticed that too, but it gives the same error once i added the quotes.